# First genomic survey of human skin fungal diversity

Tags: microbiology, mycology

"The researchers found that a single type of fungus, belonging to the genus Malassezia, is predominant on the head and trunk. Hands, which harbor a great diversity of bacteria, are home for relatively few types of fungi. In contrast, feet, including toenails, heels and toe webs contain tremendous diversity.

"Applying DNA sequencing to a study of the skin's fungi is the natural progression in understanding microbial life that co-exists on our bodies," said NHGRI Scientific Director Daniel Kastner, M.D., Ph.D. "Along with recent genome sequencing to define bacterial diversity, this analysis of fungal diversity provides a more complete human microbiome picture."

"Fungal communities occupy complex niches, even on the human body," said Heidi Kong, M.D., co-senior author and an investigator in the dermatology branch of NCI's Center for Cancer Research. "By gaining a more complete awareness of the fungal and bacterial ecosystems, we can better address associated skin diseases, including skin conditions which can be related to cancer treatments.""

[Source](http://phys.org/news/2013-05-genomic-survey-human-skin-fungal.html)

Is there another reference for this research please?

Answer (score 2):

The link is given at bottom of the article that you linked to. [It's a Nature paper](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/vaop/ncurrent/full/nature12171.html) so you need to have access rights.

Comment: Just a tip, links of the form http://dx.doi.org/whatever tend to link to academic articles.

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi I can't access that link.

Comment: The doi-based link looks like this: http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1038/nature12171

Comment: Hi @AlanBoyd, how are you doing? thanks for your reference.